# How to pass a public IP when building a vm

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

How can we pass a public ip into the linux ubuntu 14.04 machine at the time of building of the linux vm, is there any kind of template that do this or any specific steps to do this??

Answer (score 0):

See [azure-quickstart-templates/101-vm-simple-linux/azuredeploy.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-vm-simple-linux/azuredeploy.json) as a reference.

Modify the template such that, instead of creating a public IP address, it accepts the ID of an existing IP address.

- Remove the `Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses` block and any `dependsOn` references to it
- Remove the `publicIPAddressName` and `variables` (and their references)
- Add a `publicIPAddressID` variable
- In the `Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces` block, set `properties.ipConfigurationsproperties.publicIPAddress.id` to the resource ID of your existing IP address
- Deploy the template

This is a rough guide, and there may be some trial-and-error involved, but hopefully this gets you started.